# What happens if a binary search on a non-sorted data set is attempted?

Tags: java, binary-search

What happens if a binary search on a non-sorted data set is attempted?

Comment: why don't you try it ? And tell us what you observe

Comment: http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/mu.html

Comment: Its like this ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElTmbnsqF-U

Answer (score 6):

The results are unpredicable. If the data set has the target, it may or may not be found.

**EDIT** Just for kicks, I ran a little experiment. First, I picked an array size and generated an int array {0, 1, ..., size-1}. Then I shuffled the array, did a binary search for each value 0, 1, ..., size-1 and counted how many of these were found. For each size, I repeated the shuffle/search-for-each-value steps 100,000 times and recorded the percent of searches that succeeded. (This would be 100% for a sorted array.) The results are (rounded to the nearest percent):

```
Size    % Hit
 10      34%
 20      22%
 30      16%
 40      13%
 50      11%
 60      10%
 70       9%
 80       8%
 90       7%
100       6%
```

So the larger the array, the worse the effects of not sorting. Even for relatively small arrays, the results are pretty drastic.

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly not find the element you've been searching for. If the array is *mostly* sorted, then you could get lucky.

The algorithm could be implemented in a way to detect this with some probability, but unless it does a full scan of the array, there's no way to *guarantee* that a binary search will detect this error condition.

Comment: But you may find an element you're not looking for.

Comment: @ChrisGerken: I don't think so. The last comparison would see if the element is the searched for, so you'd get "not found" as the result in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Search is **meant to work on a** Sorted Array, if its done on a Non-Sorted Array, then the **result** will surely be **unpredictable and unreliable**.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Search relies on data being sorted.  It picks an element in an array and determines
1. If this is the element it is searching
2. If it is not the element it is looking for, where can it possibly find the element.

The second point relies on data being sorted to make a decision.  Imagine an unsorted data.  Just by comparing the search key with the element that we have picked, we will not be able to identify where the element could occur.

So, binary search cannot work consistently in unsorted data.